# How can I define the area "A minus B" as droppable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable, area

I have two divs, one within the other. Let's say that div B is contained entirely within div A.

I to make the area "A minus B" droppable. In other words, I want to be able to drop items on the area of A that isn't covered by B.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try making the div a droppable, div b not droppable and set a z-index for both divs leaving div b on top (z-index of b > z-index a). Haven't tried it myself, though.